# What is this C# pattern for property initialization?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'll often have objects with properties that use the following pattern:

```
private decimal? _blah;
private decimal Blah
{
    get
    {
        if (_blah == null)
            _blah = InitBlah();
        return _blah.Value;
    }
}
```

Is there a name for this method?

Comment: you just got more of the exact same answer within a 1 min period. Than I think I have ever seen on SO....

Comment: @jsmith that's because SO developers are eagerly lazy!

Comment: Ha!  Sometimes I wonder if guys get paid to sit on SO. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Lazy initialisation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)

.NET 4, when it arrives, will have a [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28VS.100%29.aspx) class built-in.

```
private readonly Lazy<decimal> _blah = new Lazy<decimal>(() => InitBlah());
public decimal Blah
{
    get { return _blah.Value; }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I knew this could be encapsulated somehow

Comment: You get the answer for extra effort.

Comment: +1 bazillion for mentioning the Lazy class. I was unaware of it, and now have another thing to look forward to.

Answer (score 10):

Lazy loading, deferred initialization, etc.

Noet that `InitBlah` should (in this case) ideally return `decimal`, not `decimal?` to avoid the chance that it gets called lots of times because it is legitimately null.

Answer (score 1):

[Lazy Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).

Answer (score 0):

This is called Lazy initialization

Answer (score -1):

lazy initializer